# XCode 6.0.1 "Launch due to background fetch" scheme setting not working?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Ok, I'm implementing background fetch and so far everything is good. The only problem that I face is that I cannot test the case when the app isn't running and is launched in the background. According to Apple you do this by simply duplicating your current scheme and checking the option "Launch due to background fetch":
[image]
However, in my case the app is still launched in the foreground like in the normal scheme. I tried to uncheck and check again the option, restarted the simulator and Xcode but the result is still the same.
The version of XCode is 6.0.1 (6A317). Any suggestions? Anyone having the same problem?

Edit: 
The problem is still present in XCode 6.1 (6A1052d). I noticed that it works on an actual device, though. (Not sure if it worked on 6.0.1)

Comment: I am also having this problem. A scheme that worked in Xcode 5 dose not in the latest version. Creating a new one as you did also dose not work. I have not tried creating a new scheme from scratch yet.

Comment: Having this issue also with Xcode 6.1

Comment: This setting is not working in Xcode 6.1.1 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only works on a device, not on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

However, you can test the background fetch in another way, by running the app in normal debug mode, then go to "Debug -> Simulate Background Fetch".

Comment: This is what I do, butthe other option not working is still a bug.